# Passing procedures with currently undefined variables to be used later - Scheme

Tags: scope, scheme

I'm fairly new to scheme and I'm a bit unsure of how to tackle the problem.

I'm trying to create a procedure that accepts a number of parameters, one being a procedure. As of right now I receive errors since the variable x is seen as undefined in the scope of the procedure. Here is a simplified set up:

```
(define (test procedure1 x)
    (define (innerTest y)
        (if (procedure y) 1 2)))
```

Here is the procedure:

```
(define (procedure1 y)
    (+ x y))
```

Running the following gives me the error "x: undefined; cannot reference undefined identifier"

```
(test procedure1 x)
```

I'm pretty sure I know the issue is that in the scope of the passed procedure, x is not visible, but I'm not sure what the solution is.

I realize the easy fix is to just have procedure1 accept x as a parameter and pass it in during the call, but for other reasons I would like to try and avoid doing that, unless there is no other solution.

Any ideas are appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like pretty much any other programming language you're likely to run into, Scheme has what's called "Lexical Scope." That is, the binding for a particular variable is determined statically by the shape of the program.

As a result, any use of a variable named "x" must occur in the scope of a binding for a variable named "x".

Perhaps you should tell us more about what you're trying to do...

(EDIT: I should add that there are about a million different ways to solve this problem; there's almost certainly one that fits your needs. I don't mean to sound negative.)

Comment: Thanks for the response. I'm mostly just trying to learn why this doesn't work. Although the procedure is **defined** outside of the scope of x, it is being **executed** from within the scope where x is defined. I would have thought that this would enable the procedure to access x, but apparently I was wrong. If this is the case, you're right, there are many many solutions and I'll just structure the code differently.

Comment: Yep. The feature you're describing is usually called "dynamic scope" (that is: use the most recent enclosing binding of the given name), and arises frequently in languages designed by people who haven't taken a PL class :). It's generally considered a bad idea, because it makes debugging almost impossible. Specifically, looking at a piece of code and trying to figure out the binding location of a given variable requires considering all the possible callers of a function (including those that haven't been written yet...).

Answer (score 1):

Formal paremeters to procedures will shadow earlier scope:

```
(define (test +)
  (+ 2 3))

(test -)
; ==> -1
```

The fact that I give the parameter the name `+` has no merit. It's just a name. The only true side effect you get by choosing a previously known name is that you shadow it such that both cannot coexist at the same time.

As you can see what you pass has nothing to do with the name of the formal parameter.

```
(define (proc y)
  (+ x y)) ; x and + are not bound so they're free/global

(define x 20) ; this is x
(proc 10) ; ==> 30
```

Any free variable not in the lexical scope is of course global. You can create a procedure before the variable but you cannot run `proc` before you have defined `x`.

From your question it looks like an attempt at parial application:

```
(define (partial proc value)
  ;; this procedure returns a procedure
  (lambda args
    (apply proc value args)))

;; how it's used
(define add10 (partial + 10))
(add10 5) ; ==> 15
```